# String array in database. match and return values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have the following data in a column `letters` in a mysql database. I saved them in `varchar`:

```
letters
["a","b"]
["a","b","d"]
["a","d"]
["d","c","e"]
["e","c","f"]
["c","f"]
["f","e"]
```

I am trying to match some elements. When I have `params[:lttrs]` as`"a"`, I want to return:

```
["a","b"]
["a","b","d"]
["a","d"]
```

When I have `params[:lttrs]` as `"c,e"`, I want to return:

```
["d","c","e"]
["e","c","f"]
```

My attempt is to retrieve all the rows and then match each of them with `include?('a')`, but with that, I can only do one element at a time. Is that the approach?

Comment: What happens when `params[:lttrs]` is "a,c,e" or "b,d,e,f"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LIKE` operator with wild card matching. This solution will be faster than using ruby. But it will be slow if you have a large table. If you provide more details about the reason for your data design we will be able to suggest alternative approaches.

```
like_params = params[:lttrs].split(",").map{|letter| "%#{letter}%"}
like = like_params.map{ "LIKE ?"}.join(" OR ")
Model.where(like, like_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like:

```
query = "letters "
r = 1
letters_arr = params[:lttrs].split(",")
letters_arr.each do |l|
  if r == 1:
    query << " like '%#{l}%'"
  else
    query << " or like '%#{l}%'"
  end
end
```

letters_found = WhateverModel.where(query)

Obviously you need to make sure that the params are handled more safely than that, but that should get you on your way.